# Using ToString() in LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm writing a LINQ query to fill a `listview` but it uses the `.ToString()` method which apparently is not allowed. When I use the below code I get the error message:

> Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Is there a way to use the `ToString()` in LINQ or if that is not possible what is the solution to converting a `DateTime` to `String` in the query. Please know that `ReleaseDateName` is a `string` and `ReleaseDate` is a `DateTime`

```
using (var db = new ReleaseInfo())
{
    lvReleaseInfo.DataSource = (from r in db.MediaReleases
                                join rn in db.ReleaseNames
                                on new { MediaReleaseID = r.MediaReleaseID, CultureCodeID } equals new { rn.MediaReleaseID, rn.CultureCodeID }
                                join plat in db.MediaPlatforms
                                on new { MediaPlatformID = r.MediaPlatformID, CultureCodeID } equals new { plat.MediaPlatformID, plat.CultureCodeID }
                                join pub in db.MediaPublishers
                                on new { MediaPublisherID = r.MediaPublisherID, CultureCodeID } equals new { pub.MediaPublisherID, pub.CultureCodeID }
                                join c in db.Countries
                                on new { CountryID = r.CountryID, CultureCodeID } equals new { c.CountryID, c.CultureCodeID }
                                join rd in db.ReleaseDates
                                on new { MediaReleaseID = r.MediaReleaseID, CultureCodeID } equals new { rd.MediaReleaseID, rd.CultureCodeID }
                                join a in db.AffiliateLinks
                                on new { MediaReleaseID = r.MediaReleaseID, CultureCodeID } equals new { a.MediaReleaseID, a.CultureCodeID }
                                where r.SectionID == SectionID
                                select new
                                {
                                    rn.ReleaseTitle,
                                    plat.MediaPlatformName,
                                    pub.MediaPublisherName,
                                    c.CountryName,
                                    ReleaseDate = (rd.ReleaseDate == null ? rd.ReleaseDateName : rd.ReleaseDate.ToString()),
                                    a.AffiliateLinkAddress
                                }).ToList();
    lvReleaseInfo.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: It's a long time ago now that this was an issue in EF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are materializing your query to list anyway, you could do the conversion on the .NET side, rather than in the RDBMS, like this:

```
...
select new {
   rn.ReleaseTitle,
   plat.MediaPlatformName,
   pub.MediaPublisherName,
   c.CountryName,
   rd.ReleaseDateName,
   rd.ReleaseDate,
   a.AffiliateLinkAddress
}).AsEnumerable() // <<== This forces the following Select to operate in memory
.Select(t => new {
   t.ReleaseTitle,
   t.MediaPlatformName,
   t.MediaPublisherName,
   t.CountryName,
   ReleaseDate = t.ReleaseDateName ?? t.ReleaseDate.ToString()
   t.AffiliateLinkAddress        
}).ToList();
```

Since the `ToString()` is called on an element from `IEnumerable<T>`, it will no longer fail. Also note the use of `??` operator in place of a null-checking `? :` conditional.

Comment: I am new to LINQ to Etityes, can you explain how the .Select portion works?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete `.Select` is just method syntax. It is the same as when you use `select` in the query syntax. `t => { ... }` is a lambda expression. It's basically saying for each element we select do whatever is to the right of the `=>` operator.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about just converting this into a Proc on the SQL server since it is a fairly complext join. Converting to a Proc would also allow me to do the logic on the SQL Server's side. Would there be a decent performance upgrade to go proc vs your method?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete I would doubt it, because an in-memory projection carries minimal performance overhead. This would not be the case had it been an in-memory filter, though, so the advice is specific to your case, when all filtering and joining is done on the RDBMS side.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So I just tested the code you provided and every name in the second select gives the error "The name XXX does not exist in the current context. The error goes away if I declare the names earier in code but I am trying to bind this to a ListView for display.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Take a look at the edit, it should fix the problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That changed the error to:

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statment.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Oops, I missed the `new`. Sorry, I don't have your data source, so I can't compile to try it out.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That is ok, I really apreciate the help and the second new made it work perfectly. I really apreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't call `ToString()` on a field until it's been deserialized. So, rather than trying to call `ToString()` in the query, simply do it on the results afterwards.

In the database the value you're operating on has no notion of `ToString()` which is why you get the error. The query may look and feel like C# code but keep in mind that under the covers that is being transformed to a SQL query like any other. After you get the list back you can write a very simple LINQ query to solve the problem.