# Getting Linq Expression error while getting Enum values. I followed different google tricks but not helpful. I'm new to Ef Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Getting Linq Expression error while getting Enum values. I followed different google tricks but not helpful. I'm new to Ef Core
I'm returning Enum Type `userRoles` to var roles by this line. But I got null.

```cs
var roles = await _context.Roles.Where(r => userRoles.Any(ur => ur.ToString() == r.Name)).ToListAsync();
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(r => __userRoles_0
> .Any(ur => ur.ToString() == r.Name ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync().

Comment: Could you paste in the actual code, the exception code is useful, but be good to see the actual code too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ToString() in LINQ queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533274/using-tostring-in-linq-queries)

Comment: The query is translated into sql. `ToString()` is not translatable to sql. Doesn't a user role have a property (column!) like `ur.Name`?

Comment: while this work fine in core 2.0 but in 3.1.3 its not working. @RenéVogt userrole include user and role class along their id.

Comment: Lots of people are having issues with code that worked in Core 2.0 and does not work in Core 3.0 nor Core 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the `userRoles` variable holds some in-memory collection (like `List`, array etc.) containing some custom `Enum` values which you want to use as a filter for an entity having `string` property.

EF Core has very limited support of in-memory collections inside LINQ to Entities query. Basically collections of primitive types and `Enumerable.Contains`.

So what you can do in this specific case is to convert the custom `Enum` values collection to string collection containing the desired names outside the EF Core query (1) and then use it with `Contains` operator inside (2):

```
var userRoleNames = userRoles.Select(ur => ur.ToString()); // (1)
var roles = await _context.Roles
    .Where(r => userRoleNames.Contains(r.Name)) // (2)
    .ToListAsync();
```