# Convert time Span(10:47:00.0000000) value into this formate("hh:mm tt")

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the `System.String ToString(System.String)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```cs
    List<ModelName> List = await (
                               linq query write here
                                select new ModelName
                                {
                                 Column Name,
                                  chkIN = VD.CheckIN.ToString(),
                                }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Not sure how the question is related to the ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC tags!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ToString() in LINQ queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533274/using-tostring-in-linq-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<ModelName> List = await (
                       linq query write here                                                           
                        select new ModelName          
                        {  
                         Column Names,  
                         checkin = VD.CheckIN.Value     
                        }).ToListAsync();  
   List.ForEach(x => x.chkIN = x.checkin.HasValue ? DateTime.Today.Add(x.checkin.Value).ToString("hh:mm tt") : "");  
        return List;
```

Comment: a bit of an explanation wouldn't hurt :)