# Convert Date formate ("yyyy MM dd") into this Date formate("dd MMM yyyy")

Tags: c#, linq

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the System.String ToString(System.String) method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
         List<ModelName> List = await (    
                           linq query write here   
                            select new ModelName  
                            {  
                             Column Name,   
                             BlacklistDate = VM.BlacklistDate.Tostring()      
                          }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Wondering why you asked virtually the same question about an hour ago -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299864/convert-time-span104700-0000000-value-into-this-formatehhmm-tt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ToString() in LINQ queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533274/using-tostring-in-linq-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

```
  List<ModelName> List = await (    
                       linq query write here   
                        select new ModelName  
                        {  
                         Column Name,   
                         _BlacklistDate = VM.BlacklistDate.Value,     
                      }).ToListAsync(); 
                         List.ForEach(x => x.BlacklistDate = x._BlacklistDate.HasValue ? (x._BlacklistDate.Value).ToString("dd MMM yyyy") : "");  
                         return List;
```

Comment: ... and added virtually the same answer. What is your goal here?